# fill table dynamically using GET request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, dom, dynamic

an empty table. To fill the product table, its content should be created dynamically by using JavaScript to insert the data into the table. The data should be requested from the webserver. You should first send an AJAX GET request to the Web service. When this request returns successfully, you should insert the returned JSON data into your table using the DOM

Answer (score 1):

You can try [datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) plugin to fullfill your scenario

***to work with this your data should be in the format of***

```
    {   "draw": 1,   "recordsTotal": 57,   "recordsFiltered": 57,   "data": [
        [
          "Airi",
          "Satou",
          "Accountant",
          "Tokyo",
          "28th Nov 08",
          "$162,700"
        ],
        [
          "Angelica",
          "Ramos",
          "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
          "London",
          "9th Oct 09",
          "$1,200,000"
        ], 
      ] 
  }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <table>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

include below scripts too

> https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
>
> https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: didint helped this?

Answer (score 0):

You can append the dynamically created html using `innserHTML`  property of`DOM` element.

**Example**

```
fetch('<some URL>')
.then((response) => {
    let data = response.json(); // Let supposed the data is in this format [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
    let tr = '';
    data.forEach(function(value) {
        tr += `<tr><td>${data.id}</td></tr>`;
    });
    document.querySelector('#table_id tbody').innerHTML = tr; //Append the data
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Or use `document.createElement` to create the element and then append it to the `DOM`

```
fetch('<some URL>')
.then((response) => {
    let data = response.json(); // Let supposed  the data is in this format [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
    let tr = '';
    let tableBody = document.querySelector('#table_id');
    data.forEach(function(value) {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.textContent = data.id
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    });

}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <table id="table_id">
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```